# How to execute stored procedure in EF7 beta8?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run stored procedure in EF7 beta8 to return me a specific data. I'm trying to do it via FromSQL command, but not sure if this is right command.

```
strSQL = wt.DataSource.StoredProc;

foreach (var p in prms)
{
    strSQL = strSQL + " @" + p.Name + " = '" + p.Value + "',";
}
strSQL = strSQL.Remove(strSQL.Length - 1); //removes last comma

var test = _dbContext.Widgets.FromSql("EXEC " + strSQL).ToList();

var test2 = _dbContext.Widgets.FromSql("SELECT * FROM Widgets").ToList();
```

Where test 2 works and returns data correctly, test1 is returning error:

> The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

I'm assuming that the data I'm returning is not part of the model. If that's the case, how can I execute stored procedure and return the raw data to List or to DataTable?

**EDIT:**

I'm trying with SQLCommand:

```
var connection = (SqlConnection)_dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = strSQL;
foreach(var p in prms)
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@" + p.Name, p.Value);
}
connection.Open();
var test = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Bus still no luck:

> No mapping exists from object type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to a known managed provider native type.

Is there any other way to execute stored procedure without mapping the entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use normal `SqlCommand` and `ExecuteReader` method to get data from a stored procedure.

Quick sample.

This code executes a stored procedure called GetWidgets which expects 2 parameters, `@name` and `@categoryId` and returns a result set which has 2 columns, `Id` and `Name`. We are reading the value from the DataReader and creating an object of `WidgetDto` and appending to a list of WidgetDto.

Your WidgetDto is a simple POCO

```
public class WidgetDto
{
  public int Id {set;get;}
  public string Name {set;get;}
}
```

And the code to execute stored proc is

```
private List<WidgetDto> GetWidgets(d)
{
    var catId= 1;
    var name ="test"
    //The above values are hard coded for demo. you may replace it 
    // with whatever your stored proc is expecting.

    var list = new List<WidgetDto>();

    const string sqlQry = "exec GetWidgets @name,@categoryId";
    using (var db = new StudentsEntities())
    {
        using (var con = (SqlConnection) db.Database.Connection)
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQry, con))
            {    
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryId", catId);

                con.Open();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var s = new GoodVm();
                        s.Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Id"));
                        s.Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name"));

                        list.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

In this example, I am using `db.DataBase.Connection` (Available in ED 6.13 version) property of my DbContext to build the connection. You can build your connection from the legacy way also by using the connection string.